# Namespace identifiers not working

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

Here is my practice code to be applied to a basic xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.xml.com/books" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
        <head>
            <title>XSLT</title>
            <style>
                h1, p {margin:0;}
            </style>
        </head>
     <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book"> 
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
            <p>
                by
                <xsl:for-each select="author">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>

                <xsl:value-of select="year"/><br/>

                Price: £<xsl:value-of select="price"/><br/>

                <xsl:if test="photo">
                    <img style="height:200px;">
                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="photo"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </img>
                </xsl:if>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. Now I've been told namespaces can be anything. Mostly URLs are used. Why is it then, that when I try this code, everything breaks, formatting, the lot. But when I change the identifier of the default namespace to "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" it works perfectly, same with the xsl namespace if it is anything other than the xsl/transform link.

Namespaces just arent clicking with me. I understand why they're there and theyre purpose, but I dont understand why things like this are as they are.

2. Also when you've two types of data, xml and html, how does the namespace know which is html and which is xml to apply appropriate formatting?

Any help greatly appreciated thank-you!

Comment: As usual, Jeni said it best.  See [The perils of default namespaces](http://www.jenitennison.com/2007/07/01/the-perils-of-default-namespaces.html).

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. If you result is supposed to be HTML, then naturally, you don't want to place the output elements in some arbitrary namespace (although many browsers will happily ignore it).

Comment: I'm just futzing around here. My main question for clarification is why do namespaces break if they are anything other than those I mentioned (both w3 links). When all guides I've read said namespace identifiers can be anything.

Comment: "*I'm just futzing around here.*" Well, it's kinds difficult to answer, when the question is not specific. -- "*all guides I've read said namespace identifiers can be anything.*" Namespace identifiers **cannot** be anything. They must conform to what has been previously agreed between you and your recipient (I presume we are talking about namespaces in your output). If your target application expects things to be in namespace X, it will break when they are in namespace Y.

Comment: I have very little idea on how namespaces work so assume what I'm asking is at the most basic level. What I'm trying to ask is why cant the default xmlns namespace name, and the xsl namespace name be anything other than those w3 links. Are said links tied to this particular format? Why cant the default xmlns link be say www.google.com? Or any other unique link? And what do you mean they cannot be anything, all guides say the opposite? That as long as they are unique they are valid?

Comment: You are asking me to repeat what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your head around the concept of Qualified Names (or QNames for short).  A lot of entities in XML, like elements and attributes, are identified by QNames, which consist of a namespace and a local name.  For example, this element:

```
<foo:bar xmlns:foo="qwertyuiop">
```

is identified by the QName

```
{quertiuiop}bar
```

Notice here that `foo` is **not** part of the QName.  Namespace prefixes like `foo` are shorthand that save us from typing namespace strings over and over again.  Also notice that the namespace string `qwertyuiop` is arbitrary.  Often, by convention, URIs are used as namespace identifiers, but that's just because it is hoped that this will prevent collisions.  If I own the `jimrussell.us` domain, I feel pretty confident in using a namespace called `http://jimrussell.us/xsl/functions`.

Consider this: to an XML processor (if it's working correctly), these three XML documents are exactly equivalent:

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="urn:foo:space">
    <foo:child/>
</foo:root>

<xxx:root xmlns:xxx="urn:foo:space">
    <yyy:child xmlns:yyy="urn:foo:space"/>
</xxx:root>

<root xmlns="urn:foo:space">
    <child/>
</root>
```

In the last example, I finally got around to using a *default* namespace, where everything without a prefix lives in that namespace.